# Texture painting issues

Tags: texture-painting

How to texture paint normal map? I texture painted the diffuse and its fine but normal map isn't correct. I don't know if the uv's are incorrect or what. And sometimes it dissappear in texture paint in material preview but we can paint. Please help me out.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean by "paint normal map", you can bake a normal map but it's not possible to paint normal map, could you please elaborate?

Comment: When i baked textures diffuse and normal. And applied to the model then diffuse is set fine but normal map isn't good when I applied to the model. So, i have to manually texture paint the normals where some parts aren't correct,  but then i have to do it in photoshop.

Comment: Adding screenshots and example images will help people better understand the problem you're dealing with.